# Arduino How can I print the unsigned long long data

Tags: string, arduino, println, unsigned-long-long-int

I am trying to print `unsigned long long` data on Serial monitor but 
 `Serial.println()` doesn't work because of not a string variable.

So I searched on the internet to convert `unsigned long long` to `String`. I came up with some solutions but none of them work. For example;

```
uint64_t pipe = 0x12345ABCD9LL;//lets assume the data is 12345ABCD9 hexadecimal
char buf[50];
sprintf(buf, "%llu", pipe);
Serial.println( buf );
```

This code doesn't work. I tried `"%lu"` , `"%lld"` as well.

I want to see what my `pipe` value is. In this case, I want to see `12345ABCD9` on the serial monitor. Is there any other way to do it ? I am waiting your response. Thank you very much.

EDIT:

when I use the `"%lu"` I see `878361817` variable on the screen(which is not what I want). But the others they are just null , empty

Answer (score 3, accepted):

How about dividing it into upper half and lower half?

Try this (not tested):

```
uint64_t pipe = 0x12345ABCD9LL;//lets assume  the data is 12345ABCD9 hexadecimal
char buf[50];
if(pipe > 0xFFFFFFFFLL) {
  sprintf(buf, "%lX%08lX", (unsigned long)(pipe>>32), (unsigned long)(pipe&0xFFFFFFFFULL));
} else {
  sprintf(buf, "%lX", (unsigned long)pipe);
}
Serial.println( buf );
```

Comment: Unfortunately nothing disappears. Thank for your time

Answer (score 1):

According to the [Arduino language reference](https://www.arduino.cc/en/Serial/Print), you can print HEX values like so:

`Serial.println(pipe, HEX)`

Another option is to create a union type to destruct the long long into two longs:

```
union longlong {
    long a;
    long b;
}
```

And then reference the separate longs as:

```
longlong i = pipe;
Serial.println(i.a, HEX);
Serial.println(i.b, HEX);
```

See the union trick [explained at hackaday](https://hackaday.com/2018/03/02/unionize-your-variables-an-introduction-to-advanced-data-types-in-c/).

Answer (score 1):

It can be done as well with this snippet; a little playing with pointers..

```cpp
  uint64_t pipe = 0x12345ABCD9ULL;//lets assume  the data is 12345ABCD9 hexadecimal
  uint32_t *p = (uint32_t *)&pipe;
  Serial.printf ("%X%08X\n", p[1], p[0]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Copy your long long number n it into a Float and then print (float,0).

Comment: That will cause a loss of information.

Answer (score 0):

This is how I made an Arduino print `long long`, and `unsigned long long` integers (in base 10):

```c++
void print_unsigned_long_long(unsigned long long val) {
    if (val < 10) {
        Serial.print((unsigned int) val);
    } else {
        unsigned long long subproblem = val / 10;
        int remainder = val % 10;
        print_unsigned_long_long(subproblem);
        Serial.print(remainder);
    }
}

void print_long_long(long long val) {
    long long positive = val;
    if (val < 0) {
        Serial.print("-");
        positive *= -1;
    }
    print_unsigned_long_long(positive);
}


void setup() {

    Serial.begin(9600);

    Serial.println("Unsigned Long Long (Expect 18446744073709551615)");
    print_unsigned_long_long(18446744073709551615ULL);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("Signed Long Long (Expect -9223372036854775807)");
    print_long_long(-9223372036854775807LL);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();

    Serial.println("Signed Long Long (Expect 9223372036854775807)");
    print_long_long(9223372036854775807LL);
    Serial.println();
    Serial.println();

}
```

This is the output, confirming correct implementation for displaying the maximum boundaries of the signed long long and unsigned long long integers:

```
Unsigned Long Long (Expect 18446744073709551615)
18446744073709551615

Signed Long Long (Expect -9223372036854775807)
-9223372036854775807

Signed Long Long (Expect 9223372036854775807)
9223372036854775807
```